# How could I find out what assertions framework I am using?

Tags: frameworks, mocha.js, assert, assertion

There are Mocha tests in the project I am working on. In these tests the `expect` keyword is used quite profoundly to do the assertions. E.g. the `excpect(result).to.be.true`. But I can not find out what framework is used to implement the `expect` keyword. I need to know that to be able to read the documentation for that framework. I.e. - to be able to Google the documentation.

Comment: There's very little information to start with here. The syntax reminds me of [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/), but I would use a debugger to find out for sure.

Comment: @GOTO0, what do you mean by using a debugger? Should I try stepping into the `expect` call?

Comment: Exactly. The path of the file where `expect` is defined should hint you the package that contains the assertion framework.

Comment: @GOTO0, it was Chai. Thanks.